# What does どうにも穏やかではなさそうだが mean

Tags: translation, meaning

> それで一体どうしたのかね？どうにも**穏やかではなさそうだ**が

My question is about the meaning of 穏やかではなさそうだ in the above.

According to the man who asked him this, he found the protagonist fainted in the park.

The translation in what I was watching was "you don't look particularly calm".

I've only seen 穏やか used in the context of not talking about people, but about other things like...

> 電話で話せないこととは穏やかではなさそうだね

Is the translation correct or is 穏やかではなさそうだ referring to something else?

Comment: どうにも doesn't really mean "particularly" but more like "somehow".

Comment: @user4092 どうにも～ない=not … by any means; no matter how hard one tries, cannot…
どうにも with positive verb=somehow???

Answer (score 1):

穏やかでない "not moderate" is an euphemistic idiom that describes something (usually about an event or a remark) is disturbing, ominous, abnormal, or alarming.

In this case, though I don't know much about the context, it doesn't seem likely to mean "(the character, behavior of) someone isn't calm". Maybe what the speaker wants to tell is that the protagonist looks so badly hurt or distressed, or himself foresees some grave complications behind the situation.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you don't think he was talking about the boy being "calm" or "unsettled", but rather that he feels some sort of unease about finding the boy collapsed in the middle of the park?

Comment: @123dahg Yes, that's the most natural reading to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use 穏やか to describe people/personalities.  (A quick search of `穏やかな人` on Google shows lots of hits.

If you look at the 2nd definition of 穏やか [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/31486/meaning/m0u/) it says, 
which fits the translation pretty well.

`２ 気持ちが落ち着いていて物静かなさま。「―な人柄」「―に話し合う」「心中―でない」`

Comment: So you're saying their translation is correct, or at least plausible?

Comment: Without more context, I can't know for sure but it seems alright?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for, but before this happened he had just woken up saying "That's right, that was a demon" (the real reason he was unconscious was that he was attacked by a monster and someone saved him.  He seems very confused as to why he was found unconscious in the park and one of the people who found him asked what I said in my question.

Comment: Is it the word 'calm' that's confusing? It also has the meaning of "tranquil", so you could negate that and do a rough translation of, "you seem roughed up" or "you seem like something has happened to you" etc.